# how to exclude sites in a firefox addon contentscript using pagemod?

Tags: regex, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, userscripts, content-script

I'm working on a Firefox Addon version of a userscript.  The addon syntax is really simple using the page-mod library.  For example:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.example.com",
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScriptFile: data.url("test.user.js")
});
```

This will run the script `test.user.js` for sites that match `*.example.com`.  However in a typical userscript I can also specify an exclude line, so that I can easily bypass subdirectories of the included url.  IOW, I want a line like this:

```
exclude: "*.example.com/somewhere",
```

But the [pagemod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) docs don't list any such option (nor does it appear to exist).  **How would I specify an exclude in this case?**

It looks like include can also accept a [match-pattern](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/api-utils/docs/match-pattern.html) built from a regex.  However, I'm having trouble imagining the regex would match *.example.com but not *.example.com/subdir (but also *.example.com/othersubdirs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not always be possible to do an exclude rule with regex in the `include` option, and it may get quite convoluted in those cases when it is possible.

Probably the simplest, most robust way to do an exclude is to add it to your `contentScriptFile`.

Something like this (untested):

```
if (/^https?.*badSite\.net.*$/.test (location.href) )
    return;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative look-ahead in a regular expression to achieve this:

```js
include: /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?example.com\/(?!somewhere).*/
```

This regular expression matches `http://example.com/`, `https://example.com/`, `http://foo.example.com/` and `http://example.com/subdir` but not `http://example.com/somewhere` or `http://fooexample.com/`.